# Flexbox not stacking in Safari

Tags: css, html, safari, sass, flexbox

Having some trouble getting my Flexbox tiles to stack at breakpoints in Safari *(For this purporse v10.0)*. Here is an example [codepen](http://s.codepen.io/danielmdesigns/debug/WGAaQw) showing what I'm trying to do.

There are quite a few Q/A's on here already on this same topic, but I have yet to find a solution that corrects my specific issue. I've tested with vendor prefixes & no vendor prefixes. removing the calc() and min-width properties! Is it something else? Here's the jist of what I'm trying to do...

```
.tile-container
   display: flex
   flex-wrap: wrap

.tile
   flex: 1
   margin: 3px
   padding: 2rem
   min-width: calc(25% - 0.75rem)
   min-height: 200px
   text-align: center
   color: #fff
   background: tomato

.tile-icon
   width: 100%
   max-width: 50px

.tile-title
   display: block
   padding-top: 10px

.tile-content
   margin-top: 30px

@media (max-width: 768px)
.tile
   width: 50%
   min-width: calc(50% - 0.75rem)
@media (max-width: 480px)
.tile
   min-width: calc(50% - 0.75rem)
@media (max-width: 380px)
.tile
   min-width: 100%
```

...the items should stack vertically on smaller screens and lay horizontally on larger. However, in Safari it's always horizontal, never stacks (when browser size is adjusted).

I can provide fall back option(s) but I'd really like help investagting where I might be going wrong with this. Can someone please help me understand what I might be overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

So I seem to have found my own answer after experimenting some more...

The solution that appears to be working is instead of `flex: 1` I was able to do `flex: 1 0 calc(25% - 0.75rem)` and the results are as expected.

Hope this helps you in the future